# Find the closest line vertex from the linestring using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point, linestring

How to find the closest line vertex from a linestring? `ST_ClosestPoint` will give a point which is not from the linestring.

Comment: Could you draw a sketch about your case with the linestrings and mark which point you would like to find. Attach also the SQL query you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

[`ST_ClosestPoint`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html) will find the closest point on a linestring. For example, locating a point on a road that is closest to a point-of-interest off to one side:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ClosestPoint(road, poi))
FROM (SELECT
  'LINESTRING (10 10, 20 20)'::geometry AS road,
  'POINT (14 10)'::geometry AS poi
) AS f;
  st_astext
--------------
 POINT(12 12)
(1 row)
```

There are theoretically an infinite number of points that are on a line, and this location is *exactly* on the road linestring:

```
SELECT ST_Intersects('LINESTRING (10 10, 20 20)'::geometry, 'POINT (12 12)'::geometry);
 st_intersects
---------------
 t
(1 row)
```

---

If the objective is to get the closest vertex or coordinate from the linestring, the road needs to be converted to a MultiPoint geometry. Here's a function that does that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_AsMultiPoint(geometry) RETURNS geometry AS
'SELECT ST_Union((d).geom) FROM ST_DumpPoints($1) AS d;'
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT COST 10;
```

Then use it similar to before:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ClosestPoint(ST_AsMultiPoint(road), poi))
FROM (SELECT
  'LINESTRING (10 10, 20 20)'::geometry AS road,
  'POINT (14 10)'::geometry AS poi
) AS f;
  st_astext
--------------
 POINT(10 10)
(1 row)
```

Comment: POINT(12 12) is not exact point want (10 10) or(20,20)

Comment: i want exact point which is from linestring is there some function..??

Comment: @user32876 updated answer to convert to MultiPoint

Comment: Could you edit your question and call closest point as closest vertex?