# Nearest Neighbor in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, php

I would like to write a php script that takes a coordinate as input and finds the nearest vertex of the road_network.

Is this possible with ST_ClosestPoint?

Or do I need nearest neighbor method?

And how could I implement the query since I don't know the geometry of the point I'm looking for?

---

I enter a random point (blue point in the picture) and the result of the 2nd to last query is the red point. The yellow line on the network is a part of my road network which is split by pgr_nodeNetwork. What I'd like the result of the query to be is either the upper or the lower vertex of the yellow line (actually the closest to the blue point)

[image: Results of 2nd to last query]

Comment: ST_DWithin will be faster http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html

Comment: I think that this returns true if the two geometries you define are within the distance you ask. Can it be applied like "find the nearest point in 100 meters" ?

Comment: select * from theuser where ST_DWithin(point , ST_GeomFromText('POINT(120.9982 24.788)',4326) , 0.1/111.325 ); will find any (if any) within the point/lat/lng (100m)

Comment: I think you want to combine it with ST_Dump, as explained [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111711/find-the-closest-line-vertex-from-the-linestring-using-postgis) with respect to two lines.

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL are you using and PostGIS?  If you are using 9.5+ and 2.2+, then <-> (nearest neighbor operator is your best bet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me you have three main options:

1. Use ST_DWithin to identify a vertex within a certain distance of the coordinates. The advantage to this is that it makes use of spatial indexes on the geometry column and will be much faster. The disadvantage is that it may not return the nearest road vertex if there isn't a nearby road, or may return multiple vertexes. The multiple vertexes could be handled by checking distance within just those vertexes, with a subquery in the SQL. This approach would be good if you know the nearest vertex will never be more than X distance.
2. Use the methods I outlined earlier (below) to find the nearest vertex in your roads table. I think this gives you more precisely what you are asking for, but the ST_Distance function does not make use of the spatial index so the resulting query may not be performant if you have a lot of roads and vertexes.
3. Use the ST_DumpPoint function to populate a new table with the vertexes. Place a spatial index on the points, and then query against this table using the [<-> bounding box operator](https://boundlessgeo.com/2011/09/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/) in the ORDER BY and limiting to one. This makes use of bounding boxes in spatial indexing, and because the bounding box is on a point rather than a line it is more exact (a bounding box on a long, curving road may fully encompass your point). If you need information on the road itself, you can include a road_id in the new vertex table and join to it. The disadvantages to this approach are the one-time creation of the vertexes (more than one time if your roads change frequently), and the time to create the table. If you care which road is being located, you may also need to make accommodations for roads that have common vertexes (intersections).

---

Earlier real-time query strategy posted earlier:

Depending on what you are trying to identify, one of the following PostGIS SQL queries should work. I've provided options to select the nearest road to the selected point, the nearest point on the road (not necessarily a vertex, or the nearest vertex on the road.

- Replace x,y with point coordinates in all examples below.
- Replace 'road' with name of line layer.
- The line layer and point need to have the SRID (I've assumed 4326).

To find the nearest line:

```
SELECT  r.gid, 
        r.geom, 
FROM public.road r
ORDER BY ST_Distance(r.geom, 
            ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y), 4326)) ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

To find the nearest point on a line (not necessarily a vertex).
This may perform slowly with a lot of lines - see vertex example below.

```
SELECT  ST_ClosestPoint(r.geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y), 4326)) as closest_pt,
FROM public.road r
ORDER BY ST_Distance(r.geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y), 4326)) ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

To find the nearest vertex in a lines layer (simpler, but less efficient?)

```
SELECT d.geom  
FROM 
(SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(r.geom)).geom as geom FROM public.road r) AS d
ORDER BY ST_Distance(d.geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x,y), 4326)) ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

The following method of finding the nearest vertex could be faster because it only dumps vertices of the nearest line, rather than all lines in the layer.
This allows the line to be selected with a spatial index prior to the dump.
Note that x, y needs to be entered twice.

```
SELECT  d.geom
FROM (SELECT 
        (ST_DumpPoints(
            (SELECT r.geom AS geom
            FROM public.road r  --PERHAPS PLACE ST_DWithin SUBQUERY HERE
            ORDER BY 
                ST_Distance(r.geom, --AVOIDS POTENTIAL BOUNDING BOX ISSUE WITH <->
                            ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y), 4326))
                ASC
            LIMIT 1
        ))).geom AS geom FROM public.road r
     ) AS d
ORDER BY ST_Distance(d.geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y), 4326)) ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

EDIT Based on @LR1234567's comment above, the ST_Distance doesn't use the index the way I expected. I believe the SQL below will do better, but may introduce some approximations the way bounding boxes are used, as described [here](https://boundlessgeo.com/2011/09/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/).

```
SELECT  d.geom,            --remove comma if not doing optionals below
        ST_AsText(d.geom), --optional
        ST_X(d.geom),      --optional
        ST_Y(d.geom)       --optional
FROM (SELECT 
        (ST_DumpPoints(
            (SELECT r.geom as geom
            FROM public.road r
            ORDER BY 
                r.geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y), 4326)
                ASC
            LIMIT 1
        ))).geom as geom FROM public.road r
     ) AS d
ORDER BY ST_Distance(d.geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y), 4326)) ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: As you mentioned, St_distance does not make use of indexes, though st_dwithin does.

Comment: WOW...!!!! I am astonished by the answers of this community. Thanks a lot you guys.  So far the last snippet works perfectly for here. Taking for granted that this is running in localhost it took 43msec to execute the query.  I need to revise PostGIS functions a bit though some of this looks really new. Thank you..!!!

Comment: @Stefanos Out of curiosity, how long does it take to run the second to last code block?

Comment: OK wait, we have an update here. I created Spatial Indexes on the road network like: CREATE INDEX ON roads USING GIST(geom). Then VACUUM ANALYZE.  Now the last snippet runs in 36ms and the second in 41msec. Normal ? (Which spatial index comes by default? R-Tree or GIST? )

Comment: It sounds kind of normal to me, but is dependent on data set, etc. A brief search seems to indicate GIST is default for spatial indexes in PostGIS with an R-tree overtop of the GIST. It looks like PostgreSQL geometry (without PostGIS) could use SP-GIST? It's not something I know very well presently. The vacuum likely helped, too.

Comment: One more question. Last query returns it as binary. Is there any way to have it as text in the query itself ? Like, not having to select again SELECT ST_AsText('010100002034080000275B8C0E39CD12419EDAB42EEEB55041')  ???

Comment: @Stefanos see edits in last code block. FYI - I believe it is a memory reference rather than binary. You can get binary with ST_AsBinary()

Comment: OK. One question here. Am I wrong or this script creates a new point? I mean, sometimes it indeed gives the nearest existing point but other times it creates a point in the nearest distance?

Comment: Are you using version 9.5 of Postgres? You could see some odd centroid behavior with <-> on earlier versions. See [here](http://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html). In that case, try 2nd to last code block. If you mean a new point in the database table (rather than view) then I see no way it could be coming from this script.

Comment: No,  SELECT version();  returns ' PostgreSQL 9.5.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'

Comment: Does the second to last script, without the <->, also create a new point?

Comment: When you say without the <-> what do you mean? No it doesn't create a new point on the database. My road network is split into nodes using pgr_nodeNetwork so the question was to find the nearest node in the network from a point I ask (outside the road network). The scripts (from second to last) indeed give me a closest point but it does not belong to any of the nodes of the network. Sometimes it does but is it accidental ?  Or what I am asking is not possible?

Comment: I added a note in the code above where ST_Distance avoids potential bounding box issues with <->. The operator makes the query run faster, but can introduce some uncertainty. If you edit your question with a screenshot I may be able to help more effectively.

Comment: Check my edit in the question

Comment: It looks like you are in QGIS. Right-click on the layer in the layers panel and choose toggle editing. Are there 3 little X's or just 2 on the selected line? I suspect you may have three vertexes on that line - one on each end and one at the midpoint.